# Displaying command line output in a table

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm running

> wmic product get name,version

from the command line to get a list of installed programs and versions.  I need to display this in a table in a c# windows form app, but I'm having difficulty with the dataGridView.  Right now I'm just storing things in a `List<string>` but I don't know how to get that to display properly in the table.  Any suggestions/help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just running `wmic product get name` and `wmic product get version`
storing each one in a separate List and then doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            rows[0] = names.ElementAt(i).Trim();
            rows[1] = versions.ElementAt(i).Trim();
            programsGrid.Rows.Insert(i, rows);
        }
```

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

First, kinda stabbing in the dark 
 Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial)

You really just need to put a datagridview on your form and then use this line

```
 List<string> t  = new list<string>();

 //Add your data

 dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
```

try and give more detail about what trouble you are having with your data grid
 if this did not answer your question

Answer (score 1):

tjernigan, maybe this helps: the frist string on your list should be "Name    Version".
Note that every following version is aligned with the caption of the column.

So, on the first string, find the IndexOf "Version" and use this position to get a substring of the others.

Regards,
Calil